# Using Where with Lists inside Lists

Tags: c#, linq, list, where-clause

I need to create a List with Data from a `List<List<T>()`. I do not need to convert the data; I only need to find Elements with specific information.

Example: `List<Countries>()`: in this List is another one containing Cities

I need to find the right City (bad example) ^^

I've tried:

```
countryList.Where(x=>x.Cities.Where(y=>y.Name.Contains("New")));
```

After searching here, I believe I need something with `select`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var cities = from country in countrList
             from city in country.Cities
             where city.Name.Contains("New")
             select city;
```

or:

```
var cities = countrList
    .SelectMany(country => country.Cities)
    .Where(city => city.Name.Contains("New"));
```

Comment: is there i way to get the Country and not the city

Comment: In my first snippet instead of `select city` at the end you could use `select country`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `countriesList.FirstOrDefault( x => x.Cities.Any( y => y.Name.Contains("New"));`

Comment: I see that this would give you the countries with all cities that have the word "new". Probably more useful, no?

Comment: I wannt every city 
What does FirstOr"Default" mean? thx for ur help

Answer (score 1):

I think you want all the cities whose name contains the keyword "New":

```
var cities = countryList.SelectMany(country => country.Cities)
                        .Where(city => city.Name.Contains("New"))
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
countrList.Where(x=>x.Cities.Any(y=>y.Name.Contains("New")));
```